# Logging Java code, in a Cordova plugin

Tags: java, android, cordova, cordova-plugins

I'm trying to debug the Java code in a Cordova android plugin. Where can I find the logs I've added to the Java code. I was unable to find a solution for this online. Any help will be appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

If you are running using eclipse you can see logs in logcat.
Add console pugin to the cordova app and check your log in the logcat:

you can give log message like:

```
Log.d("log","message ")
```

Then you search in the logs by log.. you will get all the log.